# Java android: deshabilitar el suavizado en ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imageview

Hola estoy haciendo un visor de imágenes para android.

Estoy intentando implementar la funcionalidad de zoom, pero me he encontrado con un problema: no puedo averiguar cómo deshabilitar el suavizado de pixeles en un ImageView la primera imagen muestra como se ve y en la segunda imagen, como quiero que se muestre. les agradezco su ayuda.

[image: así se ve la imagen escalada]
[image: así deseo que se vea]

Comment: Bienvenido. como estas realizando esto,es importante saberlo, agrega el còdigo, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: obten la imagen como  un drawable dale setfilterbitmap a false y luego pasaselo al imageview.